# QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor sort by field in subclass

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

### 1) Model used in the exmaple

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Car {
    
    private String color;
}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Truck extends Car { 
    
    private Clutch clutch;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Clutch { 

    private String manufacturerCode;
}
```

and the repository classes:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Car> {}
        
public interface TruckRepository extends JpaRepository<Truck, Integer>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Truck> {}
        
public interface PassengerCarRepository extends JpaRepository<PassengerCar, Integer>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<PassengerCar> {}
```

### 2. The problem

In the GUI there is a call for all "cars" so the call is from "CarRepository":

```
carRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable)
```

I can create my own implementation of "pageable" and put "sort" in there like this:

```
@Getter
public class OwnPageable extends AbstractPageRequest {
    private final Sort sort;

    public CustomPageRequest(final int page, final Sort sort) {
        super(page, size);
        this.sort = sort;
    }
```

So in this call: `carRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable)` I put my "OwnPageable" with "sort" field. And it works just fine. But only when I specify fields from `Car` not from any of the concrete implementations. If I put: `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` with property `clutch.manufacturerCode` into `ownPageable` it will not work, as `clutch` is not part of the `car` entity. That's clear.

### 3. The question

How could I sort by `clutch.manufacturerCode` in my example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is not going to be possible. You want to sort all `Car`s which can be any number of subtypes like `Suv`, `Sport` etc and those subtypes may or may not have the nested property `clutch.manufacturerCode`.

Since you are specifying property of the subtype as sort order, it will not be present in all cars and in your case, it can only sort `Car`s which are `truck`s with a `clutch`. If it was allowed, hibernate would be in trouble when it retrieves other type of `Car`s that does not have this property.

Comment: 1) thanks for the explanation 2) could you tell me what I could do in order to do this sorting ?

Comment: I think first it is about understanding the requirement. Lets say you have 1000 cars out of which 970 are `Suv` or any other type and the remaining 30 are `Truck`s. You can only sort the 30 cars. So do you want the 30 trucks retrieved first in sorted order and then 970 in any order as they not trucks? Even to implement it with native sql query, this need to be understood first